# Function for freeing array of strings

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, free

In my program I have a function called freeFx();

this function is fed two arrays and a count of records to free.

I am getting an invalid pointer error when this function is called. I don't quite understand where this error is coming from, any help would be awesome!

here is the code:

```
/* ---- LIBRARIES ---- */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/* ---- PROTOTYPES ---- */
int readFx(char** charArr, int* intArr);

/* int sortFx(char** arr, int arg2);
int printFx(char** arr, int arg2); */

int freeFx(char** charArr, int* intArr, int cnt);
char* getToken(char arr1[], int loc);
void makeRoom(char*** t, int** z, int size);

/* ---- MAIN ---- */
int main(void)
{
    char** charPntrArr;
    int* intPntrArr;
    char* fileText;
    int iniArrSize = 10;
    int recCnt = 0;
    int i = 0;

    /* array to store addresses of arrays forming the rows */

    charPntrArr = malloc(iniArrSize * sizeof(char*));
    intPntrArr = malloc(iniArrSize * sizeof(int));

    recCnt = readFx(charPntrArr, intPntrArr);
    printf("%d\n", recCnt);

    /*sortFx(pntrArr, recCnt);
     printFx(pntrArr, recCnt); */
    freeFx(charPntrArr, intPntrArr, recCnt);

    return;
}

/* ---- FUNCTIONS ---- */

int readFx(char** charArr, int* intArr)
{
    /*
    input: csv file of string arrays
    output: count of records received
    purpose: read file, store values in array and populate pointer array
    */

    char buffer[350];
    char temp[350];
    char temp2[350];
    char*** reallocTemp;
    char* token;
    int counter;
    int subLoc = 4;
    int enrLoc = 9;
    int arrSize = 10;

    /* Clear headers */
    fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin);

    counter = 0;

    /* While file stream is not null */
    while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin) != NULL)
    {

        /* Populate array within array if pntr arr has room */
        if (counter < arrSize)
        {

            /* buffer copy*/
            strcpy(temp, buffer);
            strcpy(temp2, buffer);

            /* create array for token values*/
            charArr[counter] = malloc(10 * sizeof(char));

            /* Get first token */
            token = getToken(temp, subLoc);

            strcpy(charArr[counter], token);

            /* Get second token */
            token = getToken(temp2, enrLoc);

            intArr[counter] = atoi(token);

            counter++;
        }
        else
        {
            /* Reallocate memory due to necessary expansion */
            makeRoom(&charArr, &intArr, arrSize);

            /* Realloc was successful */
            if (temp != NULL)
            {
                arrSize = arrSize * 2;

                /* Print Reallocation info */
                printf("reallocating to %d\n", arrSize);

                /* Populate values for current buffer now that you have realloc'd */

                /* buffer copy*/
                strcpy(temp, buffer);
                strcpy(temp2, buffer);

                /* create array for token values */
                charArr[counter] = malloc(10 * sizeof(char));

                /* Get first token */
                token = getToken(temp, subLoc);

                strcpy(charArr[counter], token);

                /* Get second token */
                token = getToken(temp2, enrLoc);

                intArr[counter] = atoi(token);

                counter++;
            }
            else
            {
                printf("unable to reallocate\n");
                exit(1);
            }
        }



    }
        return counter;
}

    char* getToken(char arr1[], int loc)
    {

        /*
        input: string array & location of desired string
        output: string of token at position
        purpose: grab string (char*) of certain position in given array
        */

        int loopCnt;
        char* del = ",\n";

        /* Grab first token */
        char* token = strtok(arr1, del);

        /* Loop through array to grab value at given location */
        for (loopCnt = 1; loopCnt < loc; loopCnt++)
        {
            token = strtok(NULL, del);
        }

        return token;
    }

    int freeFx(char** charArr, int* intArr, int cnt)
    {
        int i;

        printf("INSIDE FREE FX\n");
        for (i = 0; i < cnt; i++)
        { 
            printf("%d\n", i);
            free(charArr[i]);
        }
        printf("FREED ARRAYS WITHIN ARRAY\n");

        free(charArr);
        printf("CHAR ARR FREE\n");

        free(intArr);
        printf("INT ARR FREE\n");

        return 0;
    }

    void makeRoom(char*** t, int** z, int size)
    {   
        *t = (char**)realloc(*t, size * 2 * sizeof(char*));

        *z = (int*)realloc(*z, size * 2 * sizeof(int*));

    }
```

HERE IS A SAMPLE FROM THE TEXT FILE:

```
Term Code,Session Code,Campus Code,Subject,Catalog Nbr,Section,Class Nbr,Class Component,Enrollment Total,Enrollment Cap,Enrollment Availability,Waitlist Total,Waitlist Cap,Instructor Name,Instructor Email,Building Code,Room Nbr,Start Time,End Time,M,T,W,Th,F,Sa,Su,Class Start Date,Class End Date
2152,1,MAIN,SOCW,6390,6,22913,IND  - Independent Study,0,1,1,0,0,,,,,12:00 AM,12:00 AM,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,1/20/2015,5/8/2015
2152,1,MAIN,MUSI,4460,3,21831,PRI  - Private Lesson,0,20,20,0,0,Michael J Drake,mjdrake@uta.edu,,,12:00 AM,12:00 AM,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,1/20/2015,5/8/2015
2152,1,MAIN,MAE,4301,1,27674,LEC  - Lecture,0,5,5,0,3,,,NH,109,7:00 PM,8:20 PM,Y,N,Y,N,N,N,N,1/20/2015,5/8/2015
2152,1,MAIN,EE,2403,101,25557,LAB  - Laboratory,11,24,13,0,0,Jonathan W Bredow,jbredow@uta.edu,NH,148A,5:30 PM,8:20 PM,Y,N,N,N,N,N,N,1/20/2015,5/8/2015
2152,1,MAIN,SOCW,6451,68,26055,PRA  - Practicum,1,1,0,0,0,Laura S Frank,laura.frank@mavs.uta.edu,,,12:00 AM,12:00 AM,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,1/20/2015,5/8/2015
2152,1,MAIN,ARCH,3331,1,20182,LEC  - Lecture,47,61,14,0,0,Edward R Nelson,nelsone@uta.edu,ARCH,401,5:30 PM,6:50 PM,Y,N,Y,N,N,N,N,1/20/2015,5/8/2015
2152,1,MAIN,BIOL,6291,7,26391,IND  - Independent Study,0,5,5,0,0,Matthew Fujita,mkfujita@uta.edu,,,12:00 AM,12:00 AM,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,1/20/2015,5/8/2015
2152,1,MAIN,BE,6194,12,30366,IND  - Independent Study,6,6,0,0,0,Young-Tae Kim,ykim@uta.edu,,,,,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,1/20/2015,5/8/2015
2152,1,MAIN,BIOL,5698,21,27536,THE  - Thesis Research,0,5,5,0,0,Laura D Mydlarz,mydlarz@uta.edu,,,12:00 AM,12:00 AM,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,1/20/2015,5/8/2015
2152,1,MAIN,EDAD,6399,7,20089,DTN  - Dissertation,2,10,8,0,0,Daniel B Saunders,saunders@uta.edu,,,12:00 AM,12:00 AM,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,1/20/2015,5/8/2015
2152,1,MAIN,BE,3344,14,26082,LEC  - Lecture,6,10,4,0,0,Baohong Yuan,baohong@uta.edu,ERB,131,11:00 AM,12:20 PM,N,Y,N,Y,N,N,N,1/20/2015,5/8/2015
2152,1,MAIN,EDAD,6390,11,26017,LEC  - Lecture,0,10,10,0,0,Yi Zhang,lyzhang@uta.edu,,,12:00 AM,12:00 AM,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,1/20/2015,5/8/2015
2152,1,MAIN,BIOL,3454,2,20468,LAB  - Laboratory,31,30,-1,0,0,Nicholas A Long,nicholas.long@mavs.uta.edu,LS,133,1:00 PM,4:50 PM,Y,N,N,N,N,N,N,1/20/2015,5/8/2015
2152,1,MAIN,CHEM,1451,1,22411,LEC  - Lecture,118,140,22,0,0,Seiichiro Tanizaki,tanizaki@uta.edu,SH,121,9:00 AM,9:50 AM,Y,N,Y,N,Y,N,N,1/20/2015,5/8/2015
2152,1,MAIN,ME,6297,39,30394,IND  - Independent Study,1,5,4,0,0,Ashfaq Adnan,aadnan@uta.edu,,,,,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,1/20/2015,5/8/2015
2152,1,MAIN,MUSI,1243,2,21463,PRI  - Private Lesson,1,20,19,0,0,Young-Hyun Cho,yhcho@uta.edu,,,12:00 AM,12:00 AM,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,1/20/2015,5/8/2015
2152,1,MAIN,MUSI,4242,2,21728,PRI  - Private Lesson,0,20,20,0,0,Young-Hyun Cho,yhcho@uta.edu,,,12:00 AM,12:00 AM,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,1/20/2015,5/8/2015
2152,1,MAIN,EVSE,6399,44,25290,DTN  - Dissertation,1,5,4,0,0,Merlynd K Nestell,nestell@uta.edu,,,12:00 AM,12:00 AM,N,N,N,N,N,N,N,1/20/2015,5/8/2015
```

Comment: Is there some particular reason you're allocating an `int` sequence using sizing based on `int*` ? And potentially related, [stop casting `malloc` in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: @WhozCraig, nope, none whatsoever! Thanks for this, corrected it! Any idea on the invalid pointer error? The error is coming from the first call of free(charArr[i]);

Comment: I don't suppose you could throw up the first 30 or so lines of your input file into your question in a separate text list? And honestly, this is screaming for the business-end of a debugger.

Comment: Have you tried checking if (NULL == charPntrArr) after malloc ?

Comment: @WhozCraig added a sample of the file above

Comment: @jonystorm, not quite sure I'm following you on this one...are you talking about the initial malloc? or the 2nd malloc? or both?

Comment: Um. Do you realize that data is NOT comma delimited? As such the first "token" for each line will be *the entire line*. The delimiter list `",\n"` means just keep scanning until a comma or a newline or terminator are found. Is that data *tab* delimited ?

Comment: There's no harm on checking after each malloc

Comment: lol sorry @WhozCraig, I just copy and pasted straight from the excel version of the csv...let me try again...its good to go now!

Comment: Thanks for the updates.

Comment: no, thank you @WhozCraig! I really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I see, besides the brittleness of the code in general (there is MUCH I would change), the biggest problem is by-value arrays you're passing in to your reader function.

You initially size them here in `main()`:

```
charPntrArr = malloc(iniArrSize * sizeof(char*));
intPntrArr = malloc(iniArrSize * sizeof(int)); // note: fixed this. also fix in your resize fn
```

Then their **values** (the addresses held by each of those pointers) are passed into your reader here:

```
recCnt = readFx(charPntrArr, intPntrArr);
```

At various times the reader can (and does) resize those buffers, including relocating data if needed. There is no guarantee the base address stays the same. Thus when `readFX` returns, the pointers still hold the original values, but the resize efforts have long-since made those locations no longer defined as accessible.

A quick way to address this is to do the following:

- Change your `readFX` function to take its pointer parameters by address (pointers to pointers).
- Rename the input parameters in the actual function (it will make sense when you see the code below).
- Declare local vars that have the same original names, and are initialized with the dereferenced initial values of your params.
- Save the locals back to the dereferenced parameters when the function finishes.

Something like this:

```
int readFx(char*** ppCharArr, int** ppIntArr)
{
    char **charArr = *ppCharArr;
    int *intArr = *ppIntArr;

    /*
     input: csv file of string arrays
     output: count of records received
     purpose: read file, store values in array and populate pointer array
     */

    char buffer[350];
    char temp[350];
    char* token;
    int counter;
    int subLoc = 4;
    int enrLoc = 9;
    int arrSize = 10;


    counter = 0;

    /* Clear headers */
    fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin);

    /* While file stream is not null */
    while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin) != NULL)
    {

        /* Populate array within array if pntr arr has room */
        if (counter >= arrSize)
        {
            /* Reallocate memory due to necessary expansion */
            arrSize = makeRoom(&charArr, &intArr, arrSize);

            /* Realloc was successful */
            if (charArr == NULL || intArr == NULL)
            {
                printf("unable to reallocate\n");
                exit(1);
            }
        }

        /* buffer copy*/
        strcpy(temp, buffer);

        /* Get first token */
        token = getToken(buffer, subLoc);
        if (token != NULL)
            charArr[subLoc] = strdup(token);

        /* Get second token */
        token = getToken(temp, enrLoc);
        intArr[counter] = atoi(token);

        counter++;

    }

    *ppCharArr = charArr;
    *ppIntArr = intArr;
    return counter;
}
```

Invoked from `main()` like this:

```
charPntrArr = malloc(iniArrSize * sizeof *charPntrArr);
intPntrArr = malloc(iniArrSize * sizeof *intPntrArr);
recCnt = readFx(&charPntrArr, &intPntrArr);
```

The `freeFX` call can stay as it is. That's about the quickest way I can see for you to resolve this specific issue. **Note:** I did some hacking up on this code, so some things will not work with a simple cut/paste back to your code base (I have `makeRoom` returning the new size, for example), but you can hopefully still see what the root problem was.

Hope it helps.

---

**Update**

A dumbed down version with integrated allocation in the read-array and bubble-sorting of the content. I hope the OP finds it useful. This is considerably cleaner, imho, than the original version.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/* ---- PROTOTYPES ---- */
int readFx(char*** ppCharArr, int** ppIntArr);
int freeFx(char** charArr, int* intArr, int cnt);
void sortFx(char** const charArr, int* const intArr, int cnt);

/* ---- MAIN ---- */
int main(void)
{
    char** charPntrArr = NULL;
    int* intPntrArr = NULL;
    int recCnt = 0;

    /* array to store addresses of arrays forming the rows */

    /* read file and get record count */
    recCnt = readFx(&charPntrArr, &intPntrArr);
    sortFx(charPntrArr, intPntrArr, recCnt);
    freeFx(charPntrArr, intPntrArr, recCnt);
}

/* ---- FUNCTIONS ---- */

int readFx(char*** ppCharArr, int** ppIntArr)
{
    const int subLoc = 4;
    const int enrLoc = 9;

    char **charArr = *ppCharArr;
    int *intArr = *ppIntArr;

    char line[350];
    char* token = NULL;
    int arrSize = 0;
    int counter = 0;
    int i=0;

    /* Clear headers */
    fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin);
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin) != NULL)
    {
        // check for reallocation prior to insertion
        if (counter == arrSize)
        {
            // need to expand
            int newSize = (arrSize ? (2*arrSize) : 1);
            void *tmp = realloc(charArr, newSize * sizeof *charArr);
            if (tmp == NULL)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Failed to expand charArr to %d elements", newSize);
                exit(1);
            }
            charArr = tmp;

            // expand intArr likewise
            tmp = realloc(intArr, newSize * sizeof(*intArr));
            if (tmp == NULL)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Failed to expand intArr to %d elements", newSize);
                exit(1);
            }
            intArr = tmp;
            arrSize = newSize;

            printf("Resized arrays to %d slots\n", newSize);
        }

        // get tokens
        for (token = strtok(line, ",\n"), i=1; token && (i<subLoc); ++i)
            token = strtok(NULL, ",\n");
        if (token)
        {
            charArr[counter] = strdup(token);

            // next token
            for (; token && i<enrLoc; ++i)
                token = strtok(NULL, ",\n");
            if (token)
            {
                intArr[counter] = atoi(token);
                printf("%s %d\n", charArr[counter], intArr[counter]);
                ++counter;
            }
            else
            {
                free(charArr[counter]);
            }
        }

    }

    *ppCharArr = charArr;
    *ppIntArr = intArr;

    return counter;
}

int freeFx(char** charArr, int* intArr, int cnt)
{
    while (cnt--)
        free(charArr[cnt]);
    free(charArr);
    free(intArr);
    return 0;
}


void sortFx(char** const charArr, int* const intArr, int cnt)
{
    int swapped = 1, i, j=cnt;

    // simple bubblesort algorithm. note there is no string copying cone here
    //  we compare strings, and if swapping is needed, swap *pointers* in the
    //  charArr pointer array (and intArr side by side, but that is unrelated)
    while (swapped && j--)
    {
        swapped = 0; // reset swap detection

        for (i = 0; i < j; ++i)
        {
            int cmp = strcmp(charArr[i], charArr[i+1]);
            if ( cmp > 0)
            {
                char *strTmp = charArr[i];
                int intTemp = intArr[i];

                // do the swaps
                charArr[i] = charArr[i+1];
                charArr[i+1] = strTmp;
                intArr[i] = intArr[i+1];
                intArr[i+1] = intTemp;

                // something swapped so set flag
                swapped = 1;
            }
            else if (cmp == 0 && intArr[i] > intArr[i+1])
            {
                int intTemp = intArr[i];
                intArr[i] = intArr[i+1];
                intArr[i+1] = intTemp;

                // something swapped so set flag
                swapped = 1;
            }
        }
    }

    printf("\nSORTED RESULTS\n");
    for (i=0; i<cnt; ++i)
        printf("%s %d\n", charArr[i], intArr[i]);
}
```

**Output**

The following output is from the pasted sample data.

```
Resized arrays to 1 slots
SOCW 0
Resized arrays to 2 slots
MUSI 0
Resized arrays to 4 slots
MAE 0
EE 11
Resized arrays to 8 slots
SOCW 1
ARCH 47
BIOL 0
BE 6
Resized arrays to 16 slots
BIOL 0
EDAD 2
BE 6
EDAD 0
BIOL 31
CHEM 118
ME 1
MUSI 1
Resized arrays to 32 slots
MUSI 0
EVSE 1

SORTED RESULTS
ARCH 47
BE 6
BE 6
BIOL 0
BIOL 0
BIOL 31
CHEM 118
EDAD 0
EDAD 2
EE 11
EVSE 1
MAE 0
ME 1
MUSI 0
MUSI 0
MUSI 1
SOCW 0
SOCW 1
```

Comment: This helps a lot, thank you. Another thing I guess I didn't mention, we aren't allowed to use file pointers, we have to use stdin. Is there any way I can still utilize this without that?

Comment: @Dpry12 I stuffed your sample data in a local text file. Sorry, it was the easiest way for me to debug it. That should not have anything to do with the problem I pointed out. As I said in the answer, this code will NOT just cut/paste into your code base and "work" The problem I point out is, none-the-less, completely valid. I took liberty to put reading back on `stdin` regardless.

Comment: Ok, so here is a link to my updated coding, taking your advice. [LINK](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3JyOtVloC3-SlhONUZXanRkRms/view?usp=sharing)...now I am getting a "warning: no newline at end of file" error

Comment: You seem to have a pretty high warning level (good for you). C translation units (source file as far as you're concerned) need to end with a  newline to be standard-compliant. Go to the end of your source file and smack the enter/return key. save it, and compile again (if I understand that warning correctly). It should still compile and run, however.

Comment: Great. For added homework, think about how you can do this without an initial pair of allocations in `main()` (i.e. just passing in two `NULL` pointers by address to your reader. It is actually more complicated doing it like you are now. Best of luck.

Comment: Fingers crossed you're still around. I have another issue now...I am trying to sort the two arrays now alphabetically based upon the char* array...if you could help out with why I'm getting a segmentation error, I would love you long time. Here is another [LINK](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3JyOtVloC3-aWI1VnFNWVcwSE0/view?usp=sharing)...I tried implementing what we talked about above, but having trouble

Comment: You seriously need to run this under a debugger and inspect the values of pointers, indexes, etc, to determine where the wheels are falling off. A seg-fault will trip a debugger where the fault happened, and in all likelihood nearly immediately assist in rooting out your issue.

Answer (score -1):

check the return value of readFx.

Might just be easier to post the whole function.  Maybe counter isn't starting at 0

Comment: Just updated it to show all of the code! Thanks for your help in advance...also return value is 999, which is correct since we are given a file with 1000 lines and I ditch the header row at the beginning

Comment: jonystorm is on the right track I think.  I was wondering why you were always allocating 10 chars for your text.  It looks like your text tokens can be bigger than that.  Might want to allocate strlen(token) + 1 instead.

Comment: the 10 chars is due to the fact that I know the values from column 4 will never exceed 10. Sorry if that was confusing...